# what are the reasons why the wpa_cli command would timeout whilst communicating with the wpa_supplicant control socket in a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, wpa-supplicant

I'm running the `wpa_cli` command inside of a python program to check the wifi status.
The normal command to check the utility can communicate with the supplicant process is:

```
/sbin/wpa_cli -iwlext ping
```

This works fine when I run my program by hand, or test the command above manually.

When I start the process from `systemd` the command above when run from within the process times-out with

```
'PING' command timed out.
```

I'm trying to diagnose why it cannot communicate to the main process via the control socket.

- The process can call the wpa_cli command (I can run and see the output of `wpa_cli -v`)
- The process can see the iface control socket in `/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlext` ( I can run `ls -la` etc)

Answer (score 1):

The systemd unit for the python process has

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

To somewhat segregate processes.

Setting this to `false` allows the cli to build a client socket in `/tmp` for the main process socket to link to.